# C# - Use OfType and ignore inherited classes

Tags: c#, linq, generics, c#-3.0

I have a MenuStrip with lots of items and am trying to have on event they all subscribe to so I am trying to do `menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>();` and for each one I do this:

```
menuitem.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItem_Click);
```

The problem is there is a ToolStripSeperatorItem which inherits off ToolStripMenuItem and that appears is my list of items and errors because it does not have a Click event.

How can I not include these in my OfType method?

Comment: If ToolStripSeperatorItem  extends ToolStripMenuItem, and ToolStripMenuItem has a Click event, then ToolStripSeperatorItem *must* have a Click event as well, no?

Comment: BTW there is no ToolStripSeperatorItem in the .NET framework, and ToolStripSeperator extends ToolStripItem not ToolStripMenuItem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().Where(it => it.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem));
```

It seems kind of redundant, but by doing both, you maintain the return type.

Answer (score 4):

```
menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
                .Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripMenuItem))
```

Comment: Items does not have a Where method

Comment: You're right. The `Items` collection only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, so we still need the `OfType` call in there too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
menuStrip1.Items
    .OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
    .Except(menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripSeparatorItem>())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menuStrip1.Items
 .Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>()
 .Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripSeparatorItem));
```

Because you don't need an implicit cast and comparision (OfType) which is basically slower then explicit cast with Cast